# How to import font-awesome scss correctly

Tags: html, sass, webpack-4

I am trying to use an icon from font-awesome with webpack 4 via scss.
The **webconfig** file looks as following:

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const path = require("path");
const autoprefixer = require("autoprefixer");

module.exports = {
  entry: ["./src/index.js"],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "bundle.[hash].js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "html-loader",
            options: {
              minimize: true
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "file-loader",
            options: {
              name: "style.css"
            }
          },
          { loader: "extract-loader" },
          {
            loader: "css-loader"
          },
          {
            loader: "postcss-loader",
            options: {
              plugins: () => [autoprefixer({ grid: false })]
            }
          },
          {
            loader: "sass-loader",
            options: {
              includePaths: ["./node_modules"]
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "file-loader",
            options: {
              name: "[name][hash].[ext]",
              outputPath: "fonts/"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "./public/index.html",
      filename: "./index.html"
    }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {
        from: "public"
      }
    ])
  ]
};
```

I imported the scss as following:

```
@import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome.scss";
```

and use:

```
    <a class="mdc-list-item mdc-list-item--selected demo-drawer-list-item" href="#">
        <i class="fas fa-inbox mdc-list-item__graphic"></i>Inbox
    </a>
```

It shows:

[image]

a rectangle instead an icon. What am I doing wrong? 
The fully example is on [github](https://github.com/bifunctor/font-scss).

Comment: You may need to adjust the path used in the Font Awesome `_variables.scss` (which you will want to copy to your project files and import before the Font Awesome import)

Also verify the font files are being copied to the output directory correctly.

Comment: For more detailed info, refer to Font Awesome documentation for use with Sass: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/sass

Answer (score 6):

I hit the same issue importing the font-awesome scss into my project, this is what worked for me.

```
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
https://v4.webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/#getting-started
npm install sass-loader sass webpack --save-dev 
 
{
test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
use: [
  "style-loader",
  "css-loader",
  {
    loader: "sass-loader",
    options: { 
      implementation: require("sass")
    }
  },
],
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else running into an issue with the fonts not loading (e.g. showing the empty square glyph) despite Webpack (4) compiling and **file-loader** copying the fonts properly, I found an option that makes everything load as expected.

First the recommended SCSS imports with `~` node_modules path as seen in other posts:

```
$fa-font-path: '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/webfonts';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/scss/fontawesome';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/scss/light';
```

Then you'll have the **file-loader** config targeting font files (above). To the file-loader options you want to add the `esModule: false` [option](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/#esmodule). Note that this could mess with other fonts you may be importing outside of SCSS.

Basically what I discovered is the fonts would get copied, but the font file urls in the compiled CSS would show as `src: url([object Module]);`. By default file-loader turns the imported file into a module for convenience, but of course we don't need that for fonts here, so adding the option above fixes that.

Answer (score 0):

to get font-awesome for Laravel project the next worked for me:

1. first i had searched 'fa-fw' in public/css. assured it is absent.
2. `npm install --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free` - that downloaded and created files to node_modules.
3. add to `resources/sass/app.scss`

```
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid';
```

4. add to `resources/sass/_variables.scss` (not sure for this)

```
$fa-font-path:        "../webfonts";
```

5. build. `npm run dev`
6. fa now in you app.css. enjoy!