# FontAwesome not showing icons using SCSS

Tags: css, webpack, sass, font-awesome

I am trying to load Font Awesome into my project, but for some reason the icons appear blank.
The way I load the icons is as following:

```
$fa-font-path: '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/webfonts';
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/scss/fontawesome";
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/scss/light";
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/scss/brands";
```

When I use an icon, for example `<i class="fal fa-chevron-circle-right"></i>`, it gets the Font Awesome 5 Pro font and sets an icon as content, but it doesn't appear.

What am I doing wrong? Can it be a webpack problem?

Edit:
The generated css has the following:

```
/*!
 * Font Awesome Pro 5.15.1 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com
 * License - https://fontawesome.com/license (Commercial License)
 */
@font-face {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-display: block;
  src: url(node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/webfonts/fa-light-300.eot);
  src: url(node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/webfonts/fa-light-300.eot?#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"), url(node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/webfonts/fa-light-300.woff2) format("woff2"), url(node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/webfonts/fa-light-300.woff) format("woff"), url(node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/webfonts/fa-light-300.ttf) format("truetype"), url([object Object]) format("svg");
}
.fal {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro";
  font-weight: 300;
}

/*!
 * Font Awesome Pro 5.15.1 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com
 * License - https://fontawesome.com/license (Commercial License)
 */
@font-face {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Brands";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: block;
  src: url(node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/webfonts/fa-brands-400.eot);
  src: url(node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/webfonts/fa-brands-400.eot?#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"), url(node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/webfonts/fa-brands-400.woff2) format("woff2"), url(node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/webfonts/fa-brands-400.woff) format("woff"), url(node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/webfonts/fa-brands-400.ttf) format("truetype"), url([object Object]) format("svg");
}
.fab {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Brands";
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

So for some reason the svg font is an object, it compiles into the css as `url([object Object]) format("svg")`. In the scss file it's just a normal line: `url('#{$fa-font-path}/fa-light-300.svg#fontawesome') format('svg');`. What is going on here?

Comment: Look at your compiled CSS. What does the import look like? Is the correct path?

Comment: Ah.. It tries to load `src: url(node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/webfonts/fa-light-300.eot);`. That won't work.

Comment: Also, is "fortawesome" a typo? I know there is a Fort Awesome library, but not sure how font awesome fits into that.

Comment: No, FortAwesome is the package that contains the Font Awesome fonts.

Comment: But what should I make my fa-font-path to work? When I change it to 'src/assets/fonts' I get the following error:  Can't resolve 'src/assets/fonts/fa-light-300.eot'

Comment: Right on. Simply making sure.  Add any errors to the question itself, not a comment.

Comment: Oh wait, http://localhost:8080/node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/webfonts/fa-light-300.eot does load the font. So the font path isn't the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting '.scss' at the end of the style line in the path, like this:

```
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/scss/light.scss";
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/scss/brands.scss";
```

EDIT: Since you are importing the file for the styles you have to mention the whole name of the file i.e. with extension.

This worked for me.

Comment: Just tried this, didn't work. The files do get loaded but I don't think the font gets properly loaded.

Comment: If you think its a webpack issue maybe follow this question => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51059093/how-to-import-font-awesome-scss-correctly

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. The svg url was compiled as an Object in the final css:

```
url([object Object]) format("svg")
```

In my webpack.config.js I had the following rules for svg files:

```
{
    test: /\.svg$/,
    use: [
        'babel-loader',
        'vue-svg-loader',
    ],
},
```

When I removed these lines and added svg to the default file-loader it worked.